# Optimization of Get-ChildItem in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I have a Powershell script in which I need to determine whether any files have been added to a folder within the last 60 minutes. If the answer is yes, then I take those files, copy them to another directory, and execute certain code. Right now, the source directory has ~10k-20k files and it is taking a long time for the code to execute. I have tried optimization technique for gci that I've found online (including piping outputs) but none has worked. I also tried executing as a batch file by using c/ dir but I get an error saying it does not support UNC paths. Any ideas?

```
Stop-Process -name excel
$PathMX1005 = "\\UNCsourcedir"
$numberoffilesMX1005 = Get-ChildItem $PathMX1005 -recurse -include *1Hz_1*.csv | Where { $_.CreationTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-60) } | Measure-Object
If ($numberoffilesMX1005.Count -eq 0) {Exit-PSSession}
Else {   
$filesMX1005 = Get-ChildItem $PathMX1005 -recurse -include *1Hz_1*.csv | Where { $_.CreationTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-60) } .... 

rest of code }
```

Comment: You are getting the list twice. That seems unwise. Just save the returned array and use its count/length property and/or just pipe it directly to your block of code to run and avoid the counting entirely.

Comment: HI , I had a similar problem to what you are having now , I ended up ditching the get child method and instead I created a folder watcher in power shell so basically when ever a file is added to the folder it triggers and event the even checks if the file is then one I am looking for and then performs an action . This was way quicker but it can slow down the file/folder creation time . In my environment i was not even able to tell the difference it was so small, but its good to know that it can have an impact. If you would like me to upload what I did as an answer let me know .

Comment: Aside: `[DateTime]::Now` contains milliseconds; I wondered if the `where` clause recalculates `Now.AddMinutes(-60)` for every file, and if precalculating would be faster. I scanned ~22k files over UNC this way. It took 26.540 mS. Then I ran it again with the original calculation inside the where clause approach: 16.26 mS. Then to try and account for disk caches, I reran the first try with precalculation and got 16.215 mS. Then tried to print the calculation inside the where clause. I think it does recalculate every time, but the overall difference is negligible for 22k files on a LAN.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. @justinf , could you please upload what you did as an answer so that I can take a look at it? Thank you.

Comment: I will dig up the code later and post it hear , if i cant find it will just red do it quckly.

Answer (score 2):

The user of `-Filter` is preferred over `-Include` as it passes the parameters to the provider instead of having PowerShell parse results after the fact. Also, as Etan Reisner suggested, you should only pull the directory listing once, and then get the count of it for your `If` statement, and again for processing.

```
Stop-Process -name excel
$PathMX1005 = "\\UNCsourcedir"
$filesMX1005 = Get-ChildItem $PathMX1005 -recurse -filter "*1Hz_1*.csv" | Where { $_.CreationTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-60) } 
If ($filesMX1005.Count -eq 0) {Exit-PSSession}
Else {   
    rest of code }
```

Comment: You don't really want to run the file list into measure-object, throw it away, and store the measurements in `$filesMX1005`, do you?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler You're right, lazy me using copy/paste and not double checking my work. Updated!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to what you are having now , I ended up ditching the get child method and instead I created a folder watcher in power shell so basically when ever a file is added to the folder it triggers and event the even checks if the file is then one I am looking for and then performs an action . This was way quicker but it can slow down the file/folder creation time.

I came up with this idea after reading the Scripting Guys blog post so I will just link it hear . If you need any help ask .

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/07/17/use-powershell-to-monitor-for-the-creation-of-new-files.aspx